# Get GPS data while App is running background in Android using LocationListener

Tags: android, background, gps

i have problem with my Android application.I need an application that will get in background GPS location while open another application.application run in background but i want to also get GPS location in background.

create start and stop button for get gps location it work properly but when click on home button gps stop to gettting location

Here is My code..

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);

            /* get TextView to display the GPS data */
            txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

            /* the location manager is the most vital part it allows access 
             * to location and GPS status services */
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ,10000,10, this);
           // locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10 * 1000L, 0, this);

            btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
            btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstop);


            btnShow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Trip Start.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    txtLat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    onResume();
                    btnShow.setEnabled(false);
                    btnStop.setEnabled(true);

                }
            });

            Button btnstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstop);
            btnstop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                 onPause();
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Trip Ended.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 btnShow.setEnabled(true);
                 btnStop.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });
            }
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            if (location == null) {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Searching for your location.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10000, 10,locationListener);
                  onLocationChanged(location);
             }
             else
             {

            double cell_lat=location.getLatitude();
            double cell_long=location.getLongitude();
            double altitude=location.getAltitude();
            double accuracy=location.getAccuracy();                      

            String status="true";

            sb = new StringBuilder(512);

            noOfFixes++;

            /* display some of the data in the TextView */

            sb.append("Tracking: ");
            sb.append(noOfFixes);
            sb.append('\n');
            sb.append('\n');

            sb.append("Londitude: ");
            sb.append(location.getLongitude());
            sb.append('\n');

            sb.append("Latitude: ");
            sb.append(location.getLatitude());
            sb.append('\n');

            sb.append("Altitiude: ");
            sb.append(location.getAltitude());
            sb.append('\n');

            sb.append("Accuracy: ");
            sb.append(location.getAccuracy());
            sb.append("ft");
            sb.append('\n');        

            txtLat.setText(sb.toString());
    }
      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                /* this is called if/when the GPS is disabled in settings */
                Log.v(tag, "Disabled");

                /* bring up the GPS settings */
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                Log.v(tag, "Enabled");
                Toast.makeText(this, "GPS Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                /* This is called when the GPS status alters */
                switch (status) {
                case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                    Log.v(tag, "Status Changed: Out of Service");
                    Toast`enter code here`.makeText(this, "Status Changed: Out of Service",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                    Log.v(tag, "Status Changed: Temporarily Unavailable");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Status Changed: Temporarily Unavailable",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                    Log.v(tag, "Status Changed: Available");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Status Changed: Available",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
     @Override
            protected void onResume() {
                /*
                 * onResume is is always called after onStart, even if the app hasn't been
                 * paused
                 * 
                 * add location listener and request updates every 1000ms or 10m
                 */
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, this);
                super.onResume();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPause() {
                /* GPS, as it turns out, consumes battery like crazy */
                locationManager.removeUp`enter code here`dates(this);
                super.onPause();
            }

@Override
           public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
               if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
                   System.out.println("KEYCODE_HOME");                                  
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Home Button.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                   
                   this.moveTaskToBack(true);
                   //showDialog("'HOME'");                   
                   return true;
               }
               if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
                   System.out.println("KEYCODE_BACK");                 
                  finish();
                   showDialog("'BACK'");                   
                   return true;
               }
               if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)) {
                   System.out.println("KEYCODE_MENU");
                   //showDialog("'MENU'");
                   return true;
               }
               return false;
           }

               void showDialog(String the_key){
               AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
               builder.setMessage("You have pressed the " + the_key + " button. Would you like to exit the app?")
                     .setCancelable(true)
                      .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                              dialog.cancel();
                              finish();
                          }
                      })
                      .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                               dialog.cancel();
                          }
                      });
               AlertDialog alert = builder.create();    
               alert.setTitle("GPS.");
               alert.show();
           }
```

Comment: Android `Service` is a background task. You can use it

Answer (score 1):

I found this code somewhere It worked for me [LINK](https://gist.github.com/amitabhsarkar/30e04482ed0fc707d6be), I had modified the code according to my requirement, give it a try.

It saves data in the database from the background service, you just need to start the service from an activity, NOTE: it will save in Database only if the distance of first location is more than the given minimum distance.

```
public class BackgroundLocationService extends Service implements
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private static final String TAG = "BackgroundLocationService";

IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

private LocationClient mLocationClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
// Flag that indicates if a request is underway.
private boolean mInProgress;

private Boolean servicesAvailable = false;

private double previousLatitude = 0;

private double previousLongitude = 0;

private SharedPreferences stopLocatinServicePreferance;

private float[] distance;

// public static boolean isStopSelf = false;

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public BackgroundLocationService getServerInstance() {
        return BackgroundLocationService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mInProgress = false;
    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    // Use high accuracy
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    // Set the update interval to 5 seconds
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(Constants.UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    // Set the fastest update interval to 1 second
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(Constants.FASTEST_INTERVAL);

    servicesAvailable = servicesConnected();

    /*
     * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to handle
     * callbacks.
     */
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

}

private boolean servicesConnected() {

    // Check that Google Play services is available
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    // If Google Play services is available
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {

        return true;
    } else {

        return false;
    }
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    if (!servicesAvailable || mLocationClient.isConnected() || mInProgress)
        return START_STICKY;

    setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();
    if (!mLocationClient.isConnected() || !mLocationClient.isConnecting()
            && !mInProgress) {
        appendLog(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date())
                + ": Started", Constants.LOG_FILE);
        mInProgress = true;
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

/*
 * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to handle
 * callbacks.
 */
private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded() {
    if (mLocationClient == null)
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
}

// Define the callback method that receives location updates
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Report to the UI that the location was updated
    String msg = Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + ","
            + Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    Log.d("debug", msg);
    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
    String timeStamp = s.format(new Date());
    System.out.println("TimeStamp  ddMMyyyyhhmmss =" + timeStamp);

    if (isDistanceAccountable(location.getLatitude(),
            location.getLongitude(), previousLatitude, previousLongitude)) {
        DatabaseHelper dbm = DatabaseHelper
                .getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_LATLONG, location.getLatitude() + "@"
                + location.getLongitude());
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_TIMESTAMP, timeStamp);
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_STATUS, "0");
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_USER_ID, "");
        dbm.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_TRACKINFO_TABLE, cv);
        // }

        // Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        appendLog(msg, Constants.LOCATION_FILE);

    }
    previousLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    previousLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    stopLocatinServicePreferance = getSharedPreferences("SERVICE_PREF", 0);
    boolean check = stopLocatinServicePreferance.getBoolean("isStop", true);
    Log.e(TAG, "isStop?" + check);
    if (check) {
        Log.e(TAG, "is self stoping ");
        if (mLocationClient != null) {
            mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
            // Destroy the current location client
            mLocationClient = null;
        }
        this.stopSelf();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns true if distance is grater than MINIMUM_DISTANCE_ACCOUNTABLE
 * NOTE: returns true if there is no previousLatitude,previousLongitude, it
 * means this is first time it needs to save the data
 * 
 * @param currentLatitude
 * @param currentLongitude
 * @param previousLatitude
 * @param previousLongitude
 * @return
 */
private boolean isDistanceAccountable(double currentLatitude,
        double currentLongitude, double previousLatitude,
        double previousLongitude) {

    distance = new float[1];
    if (previousLatitude > 0 && previousLongitude > 0) {

        Location.distanceBetween(currentLatitude, currentLongitude,
                previousLatitude, previousLongitude, distance);

        Log.v(TAG + " > isDistanceAccountable()", "previousLatitude = "
                + previousLatitude + "previousLongitude = "
                + previousLongitude + " currentLatitude =  "
                + currentLatitude + " , currentLongitude = "
                + currentLongitude);
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG + " > isDistanceAccountable()", "previousLatitude = "
                + previousLatitude + "previousLongitude = "
                + previousLongitude);
        return true;
    }

    if (distance[0] > Constants.MINIMUM_DISTANCE_ACCOUNTABLE) {

        Log.v(TAG + " > isDistanceAccountable()", "Distance = "
                + distance[0] + "return true");
        return true;
    } else {

        Log.v(TAG + " > isDistanceAccountable()", "Distance = "
                + distance[0] + "return false");
        return false;
    }

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

public String getTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    return mDateFormat.format(new Date());
}

public void appendLog(String text, String filename) {
    File logFile = new File(filename);
    if (!logFile.exists()) {
        try {
            logFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        // BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile,
                true));
        buf.append(text);
        buf.newLine();
        buf.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try {
        // Turn off the request flag
        mInProgress = false;
        if (servicesAvailable && mLocationClient != null) {
            mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
            // Destroy the current location client
            mLocationClient = null;
        }

        appendLog(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date())
                + ": Stopped", Constants.LOG_FILE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG + " > onDestroy()", e.toString());
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

/*
 * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the client
 * finishes successfully. At this point, you can request the current
 * location or start periodic updates
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    // Request location updates using static settings
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
    appendLog(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date())
            + ": Connected", Constants.LOG_FILE);

}

/*
 * Called by Location Services if the connection to the location client
 * drops because of an error.
 */
@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // Turn off the request flag
    mInProgress = false;
    // Destroy the current location client
    mLocationClient = null;

    appendLog(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date())
            + ": Disconnected", Constants.LOG_FILE);
}

/*
 * Called by Location Services if the attempt to Location Services fails.
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    mInProgress = false;

    /*
     * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects. If the error
     * has a resolution, try sending an Intent to start a Google Play
     * services activity that can resolve error.
     */
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {

        // If no resolution is available, display an error dialog
    } else {

    }
}
```

}

Here is the supporting class.

```
public final class Constants {

// Milliseconds per second
private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 100;
// Update frequency in seconds
private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 10;
// Update frequency in milliseconds
public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND
        * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
// The fastest update frequency, in seconds
private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 10;
// A fast frequency ceiling in milliseconds
public static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND
        * FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
// Stores the lat / long pairs in a text file
public static final String LOCATION_FILE = "sdcard/location.txt";
// Stores the connect / disconnect data in a text file
public static final String LOG_FILE = "sdcard/log.txt";
// Minimum accountable distance in meters
public static final float MINIMUM_DISTANCE_ACCOUNTABLE = 50;

/**
 * Suppress default constructor for noninstantiability
 */
private Constants() {
    throw new AssertionError();
}
```

}

Comment: Dont forget to add google play service library to your project